# calculation of argument without calculator

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

what is the most efficient way to calculate the argument of
$$
\frac{e^{i5\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/3}}{e^{i\pi/2}-e^{-i\pi/3}}
$$  without calculator ?

i tried to use $\arg z_1-\arg z_2$ but the argument of $e^{i5\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/3}$ take some time .
is there a formula to calculate the argument of that kind of complex numbers ?

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: at the end i will get complex number that i can't find it's argument without calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Sketch the points $A=e^{i5\pi/6}$, $B=e^{-i\pi/3}$ and $C=e^{i\pi/2}$ on the unit circle, and use geometrical arguments to calculate the angle between $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$.

Should boil down to a very simple use of the Central Angle theorem.

Answer (score 3):

First factor out $\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}3}$ both in the numerator and denominator:
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}6}-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}3}}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}3}} =
\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}6+\tfrac{i\pi}3}-1}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2+\tfrac{i\pi}3}-1}=\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{7i\pi}6}-1}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}6}-1}.$$
Then factor the exponentials of half the arguments
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{7i\pi}6}-1}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}6}-1}= \frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{7i\pi}{12}}}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}{12}}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{7i\pi}{12}}-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{-7i\pi}{12}}}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}{12}}-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{5i\pi}{12}}}. $$
Can you end the calculations?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

multiply the numerator and the denominator by $$e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

and use the fact that

$$\arg(1-e^{i\theta})=\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}$$